# What is the fastest way to replicate sentences by replacing words according to word list?

Tags: python

I have a word list and some sentences I need to replicate:

```
wordlist_dict = {
    'class1': ['word_a', 'word_b', 'word_c'],
    'class2': ['word_d', 'word_e'],
    'class3': ['word_f', 'word_g', 'word_h', 'word_i', 'word_a']
}

sent_list = [
    "I have a sentence with word_g",
    "And another sentence with word_d",
    "Don't forget word_b",
    "no keyword here",
    "Last sentence with word_c and word_e"
]
```

My expected results are:

```
I have a sentence with word_f
I have a sentence with word_h
I have a sentence with word_i
I have a sentence with word_a
And another sentence with word_e
Don't forget word_a
Don't forget word_c
Last sentence with word_a and word_d
Last sentence with word_a and word_e
Last sentence with word_b and word_d
Last sentence with word_b and word_e
Last sentence with word_c and word_d
```

Here is my method:

```
import re

pattern_list = []
pattern_all = ''
wordlist = sorted(wordlist_dict.values())
for v in wordlist:
    pattern_list.append('({})+'.format('|'.join(v)))
    pattern_all += '|' + '|'.join(v)
pattern_all = '({})+'.format(pattern_all[1:])
print(pattern_list)
# ['(word_a|word_b|word_c)+', '(word_d|word_e)+', '(word_f|word_g|word_h|word_i)+']
print(pattern_all)
# (word_a|word_b|word_c|word_d|word_e|word_f|word_g|word_h|word_i)+

new_sent_list = []
for sent in sent_list:
    match_list = re.findall(pattern_all, sent)
    print(match_list)
    if match_list:
        for match in match_list:
            for i in range(len(pattern_list)):
                if re.search(pattern_list[i], sent):
                    if match in wordlist[i]:
                        match_wordlist = wordlist[i]
                        match_wordlist.remove(match)
                        for word in match_wordlist:
                            new_sent_list.append(sent.replace(match, word))
                    else:
                        continue
```

And I wonder if there is any way more efficient to do this because my word list and sentence list are much larger than in the example. Thanks in advance.

Update: I just realized there are words that belong to more than one class and sentences that have more than one keyword, so my code doesn't work now.

Comment: If your code is otherwise working, you may ask on [codereview.se]. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you could "invert" the `wordlist_dict` to a dictionary mapping words to their classes. Here, I'll assume that each word is in only one class, otherwise it get's a bit more complicated.

```
wordclass_dict = {w: c for c in wordlist_dict for w in wordlist_dict[c]}
```

Next, you can find all the occurrences of any of the words, using the `pattern` to (a) get all the words classes, and (b) create a template for re-formatting the sentence. Note that I wrap the pattern into word boundaries `\b` so it does not match word-fragments.

```
pattern = r"\b(" + "|".join(wordclass_dict) + r")\b"
classes = [wordclass_dict[c] for c in re.findall(pattern, sentence)]
template = re.sub(pattern, "{}", sentence)
```

Now, you can iterate the [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) of all the possible replacements and substitute them:

```
for prod in itertools.product(*(wordlist_dict[c] for c in classes)):
    print(template.format(*prod))
```

This way, the result for sentence `"And another sentence with word_a and word_d"` is:

```
And another sentence with word_a and word_d
And another sentence with word_a and word_e
And another sentence with word_b and word_d
And another sentence with word_b and word_e
And another sentence with word_c and word_d
And another sentence with word_c and word_e
```

This should be considerably faster than your approach (did not time it, though), as it only searches twice for the `pattern`, whereas you search for each individual pattern separately. Also, this works for sentences that have more than one placeholder word.

---

If a word *can* be in multiple classes, you can use this:

```
wordclass_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)
for c in wordlist_dict:
    for w in wordlist_dict[c]:
        wordclass_dict[w].append(c)

# pattern, classes, template as above

for prod in itertools.product(*([w for c in cls for w in wordlist_dict[c]] 
                                for cls in classes)):
    print(template.format(*prod))
```

You *could* also `extend` the `wordclass_dict` entries with all the words thenselves, instead of their class names, making the `product` much simpler, but at the price of potentially much higher space requirements, depending on the size of the word classes and the "overlap".

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative version that implements the following idea: have an inverted dictionary "word -> class" for a quick lookup. This assumes the mapping is invertable. Then, kick off `replace()` to print the replacement on all other words within the word class.

```
def replace(s, v, c):
    for w in filter(lambda w: w != v, wordlist_dict[c]):
        print(s.replace(v, w))

def invert(d):
    inv = {}
    for (c,ws) in d.items():
        for w in ws:
            inv[w] = c
    return inv

inv_dict = invert(wordlist_dict)

for s in sent_list:
    for w in s.split():
        if w in inv_dict:
            replace(s, w, inv_dict[w])
            break
```

Comment: I just realized there are words that belong to more than one class and sentences that have more than one keyword, but thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import re
wordlist_dict = {
'class1': ['word_a', 'word_b', 'word_c'],
'class2': ['word_d', 'word_e'],
'class3': ['word_f', 'word_g', 'word_h', 'word_i']
}

sent_list = [
  "I have a sentence with word_g",
  "And another sentence with word_d",
  "Don't forget word_b",
  "no key word here"
]
final_data = [filter(lambda x:x!=''.join(re.findall('(?<=\s)[a-zA-Z]+_[a-zA-Z]+$', i)), [c for a, c in wordlist_dict.items() if any(h.endswith(''.join(re.findall('(?<=\s)[a-zA-Z]+_[a-zA-Z]+$', i))) for h in c)][0]) for i in sent_list]
new_final_data = [a for i, a in enumerate(final_data) if not any(c in d for d in final_data[:i] for c in a)]
second_final_data = reduce(lambda x, y:x+y, [[a[:-6]+b for b in c] for a, c in zip(sent_list, new_final_data)])
```

Output:

```
['I have a sentence with word_f', 'I have a sentence with word_h', 'I have a sentence with word_i', 'And another sentence with word_e', "Don't forget word_a", "Don't forget word_c"]
```

Comment: Sorry but I'm having difficulty in reading your code. Could you explain a little bit? Also I just realized there are words that belong to more than one class and sentences that have more than one keyword.

Comment: @T.Stark If it comforts you, I'm having trouble reading that code, as well. :-P Ajax, maybe you could break that "one-liner" down to many lines, or extract that (identical?) `join` part into a `lambda`?